# Remove duplicates from table in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I found duplicates in my table by doing below query.

```
SELECT name, id, count(1) as count
  FROM [myproject:dev.sample] 
  group by name, id 
  having count(1) > 1
```

Now i would like to remove these duplicates based on id and name by using DML statement but its showing '0 rows affected' message.
Am i missing something?

```
DELETE FROM PRD.GPBP WHERE
    id not in(select id from [myproject:dev.sample] GROUP BY id) and 
    name not in (select name from [myproject:dev.sample] GROUP BY name)
```

Comment: @RyanWilson If he deletes using his 1st query, he will end up deleting all records for the group not just the duplicates.

Comment: can you mention the query?

Comment: @RyanWilson His query will return all records with count greater than 1, agreed. But the `delete` will remove all records for that group of `name and id`.

Comment: id is not unique in my table..thats the reason i am taking the duplicates on name and id

Comment: @NikhilBOORLA Do you have an identity column on your table? Something to differentiate record 1 and record 2 which have the same id and name?

Comment: @NikhilBOORLA I posted an answer. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest, you create a new table without the duplicates. Drop your original table and rename the new table to original table.

You can find duplicates like below:

```
Create table new_table as 
Select name, id, ...... , put our remaining 10 cols here
FROM(
SELECT *, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition by name , id Order by id) as rnk
FROM [myproject:dev.sample] 
)a
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

Then drop the older table and rename `new_table` with old table name.

Answer (score 0):

Below query (BigQuery Standard SQL) should be more optimal for de-duping like in your case

```
#standardSQL
SELECT AS VALUE ANY_VALUE(t)
FROM `myproject.dev.sample` AS t
GROUP BY name, id
```

If you run it from within UI - you can just set `Write Preference` to `Overwrite Table` and you are done

Or if you want you can use DML's `INSERT` to new table and then copy over original one

Meantime, the easiest way is as below (using DDL)

```
#standardSQL
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `myproject.dev.sample` AS
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT AS VALUE ANY_VALUE(t)
  FROM `myproject.dev.sample` AS t
  GROUP BY name, id
)
```